# does pip3 install only in my environment?

Tags: pip, virtualenv

If i created a virtual environment using the command `virtualenv venv` then i activate it `source venv/bin/activate`, my terminal now looks like this

```
(venv) haziq@vita-workstation2:~$
```

does installing packages now install only in my environment or does it install globally? Example

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: Virtual env creates a folder, so if you cd into the folder you've created with it, it's gonna install to that specific folder. It can't install globally by default unless you specify sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `source` command you are activating the **virtual environment**, which can be noticed by (venv) in your terminal (that's the name of your virtual environment).
Every package you are installing now will only be available in your virtual environment.
You can view them in your created virtual environment directory.